# Treeview from XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, treeview

This is my XML

```
<Template>
  <Criteria />
  <BatchTemplates>
    <All Checked="True">
      <Income>True</Income>
      <Expenditure>True</Expenditure>
      <DonationIncome>True</DonationIncome>
      <EventIncome>True</EventIncome>
      <ChequePayment>True</ChequePayment>
      <Journal>True</Journal>
      <GiftAidDonationIncome>True</GiftAidDonationIncome>
      <ConfirmedGiftAid>True</ConfirmedGiftAid>
      <Commitment>True</Commitment>
      <AccruedIncome>True</AccruedIncome>
    </All>
  </BatchTemplates>
</Template>
```

This is the code I use to populate the tree view in the form

```
' to initialise
    rNode = tvBatchTemplates.Nodes.Add("All", "All")
    rNode.Tag = "All"
    rNode.Checked = True

    For Each BatchTemplate As objBatchTemplates In BatchTemplate_Collection
        pNode = rNode.Nodes.Add(BatchTemplate.Name)
        pNode.Tag = BatchTemplate.Id
        pNode.Checked = True
    Next

' to populate the tree view
    xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Template/BatchTemplates/All")
    tvBatchTemplates.Nodes(0).Checked = xmlNodeList.Item(0).Attributes(0).Value
    If xmlNodeList.Count > 0 Then Call PopulateTreeViews(xmlNodeList.Item(0), tvBatchTemplates.Nodes(0))

Private Sub PopulateTreeViews(ByRef xmlNode as XMLNode, ByRef ctlTreeviewNode as TreeNode)

    For intIndex As Integer = 0 To ctlTreeViewNode.Nodes.Count - 1

        If (Replace(ctlTreeViewNode.Nodes(intIndex).Text, " ", "")) = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode(Replace(ctlTreeViewNode.Nodes(intIndex).Text, " ", "").Name Then _
            ctlTreeViewNode.Nodes(intIndex).Checked = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode(Replace(ctlTreeViewNode.Nodes(intIndex).Text, " ", "").InnerText
    Next

End Sub
```

The problem I have is, this code adds an extra set of nodes onto the treeview exactly the same as the ones which already exist.[image: as shown here]

There are no other events that are firing(I have checked).

Comment: There is not enough code there to replicate your issue, where is xmlNode defined and populated? Please try and provide a minimal example that compiles

Comment: @MattWilko, hope this is enough. The XML file which is shown above is fine I guess. It is saved to a database and then retrieved to populate the treeview

Comment: If you execute the 'to initialise' code and the ' to populate the tree view' code you will have the same items twice in the treeview.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Nope sorry @dbasnett, I got the answer. It is because I am passing the treeview node as ByRef. If I pass it as ByVal it seems to work. Was looking for someone to shed more light on why this is the case.